Headless cms with next js
How to create a site where changes made in the WordPress site automatically reflect in the Next.js site?
I searched everywhere on Google and YouTube but didn't get a positive response. I hope to receive a helpful reply on Stack Overflow.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Assuming you are using next 14.
You should use Incremental Static Regeneration

On-demand revalidation with revalidatePath
For a more precise method
of revalidation, invalidate pages on-demand with the revalidatePath
function.
For example, this Server Action would get called after adding a new
post. Regardless of how you retrieve your data in your Server
Component, either using fetch or connecting to a database, this will
clear the cache for the entire route and allow the Server Component to
fetch fresh data.
'use server'   

import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'   

export async function createPost() {   
  // Invalidate the /posts route in the cache
  revalidatePath('/posts') 
}


Basically when data changes you call a route on your next app to revalidate the cache.
